# MacOS Keyboard shortcut to switch finder windows

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

You know how in Chrome in MacOS, you can do `CMD + 1` to go to the first tab or `CMD + 2` to go to the second, etc...

How can I add a keyboard shortcut in MacOS to do this as well with finder tabs in one window? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To move between tabs, use <kbd>Control+Tab</kbd>. Include <kbd>Shift</kbd> to reverse direction.

While in Finder, if you click on the Window menu, you will see an item for Show Next Tab. At the right of that is “^⇥”, which tells you the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Control+Tab</kbd>. [Here](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/what-are-those-symbols-shown-in-menus-cpmh0011/mac) is an Apple list of those symbols. You can also see them by opening the Keyboard Viewer. Enable that in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard > “Show keyboard and emoji viewers in menu bar”, or open “/System/Library/Input Methods/KeyboardViewer.app”.

You can also set up your own key combination for this in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts. Select App Shortcuts, click +, select All Applications or Finder, enter “Show Next Tab” for the Menu Title, and enter the keys you like for the Keyboard Shortcut.

To move between windows of the current application (not just Finder), use <kbd>⌘+`</kbd> (<kbd>Command + Grave Accent</kbd> [left of <kbd>1</kbd> key]). Include <kbd>Shift</kbd> to reverse direction.